# Windows 8.1 synchronous execution

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

I have to migrate my code to Windows 8.1. Problem is that 8.1 makes javascript(not WinJs) asynchronous when i introduce native call. An example scenario.

```
f1(){
window.external.notify();(call to native c# code which calls f2 using Invokescript)
}

f2(){
//do stuff
}

 f3(){
//do stuff
 }

f1();
f3();
```

The execution sequence is f1,f3 and then f2. f3 does not wait for the native call. I need to rectify this. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to wait for the end of the call in Javascript, so I'd suggest using some kind of callback mechanism. Basically, only call `f1`, and pass the name of the next function to be executed in parameter to your notify call:

```
f1(){
window.external.notify("f3");
}

f2(){
//do stuff
}

 f3(){
//do stuff
 }

f1();
```

Then, in the `ScriptNotify` event, retrieve the name of the function to execute, and use `InvokeScript` to execute it when done:

```
void wb_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
     // Do whatever you need
     // ...

     // Resume execution of Javascript code
     wb.InvokeScript(e.Value, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what in the case when f3() returns a value.Where can i assign that value.

Comment: @Query21 Just rethink your code flow. Basically, instead of doing `f2(); var a = f3(); whatever;`, create a function callback that does `function callback() { var a = f3(); whatever; }`